# Returning pointer in java

Tags: java

I have two classes and they have same static method name and function and third class which I need to call it under conditional case because I have two and I need to decide which one to be called depended on some case

so Can I make this conditional statement`if(m==n) {return new Class A()}
else {return new Class B()`
inside a method in Class c that I can use it to return an object to point a method from Class A or Class B

Comment: Please, post your code to help you

Comment: 1) Java doesn't have *pointers*. --- 2) Why create instance of class, if method to be called is `static`?

Comment: Yes if A and B both extend the same class or implement the same interface and the function returns the superclass (Object works always) or interface.

Comment: Don't just describe your code, show it as [mcve] which explains your situation.

Comment: Methods like one you propose are called factories or virtual constructors.  All those classes have to have a common parent or interface.  Java has references, not pointers a la C or C++. The distinction matters.

Comment: Mr. Andreas thanks for your response , because just I need to use this object as pointer to point to some method inside that class so I have create it

Comment: As @Andreas says, "pointer" means something in programming languages, and JAva doesn't have them. You probably don't mean "pointer", but you're doing to have to do some work to describe what you actually mean.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want from your question, but it seems very likely that the answer is "don't do that". It's likely that static methods are your problem. Fix it by making them not static.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 method reference.

Since you didn't show *any* code, it's impossible to know what your method signature is, so I'll assume `void X()`, i.e. no parameters and no return value.

```
Runnable r = (m==n ? A::mymethod : B::mymethod);
r.run();
```

If the signature (excl. method name) is different, you need to use a functional interface other than `Runnable`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for this is to return an `Object` (which is the closest thing you get to `void *` in Java) and use instanceof to know which class you got:

```
Object getMyObject(int m, int n) {
   if(m==n) {
      return new Class A();
   }
   else {
      return new Class B();
   }
}

void useObject(int m, int n)
{
   Object o = getMyObject(m, n);
   if (o instanceof A) {
      A a = (A)o;
      a.doSomething();
   } else if (o instanceof B) {
      B b = (B)o;
      b.doSomethingElse();
   }
}
```